# Connecting JQuery UI - Tooltip with Raphael 2.x

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, button, tooltip, raphael

im trying to set up an existing jquery solution for tooltips on my Raphael JS Interface.
Raphael Wraps inside an  a  tag. I really dont know how to call it.

I dont wanna use another solution, because im using it already on the whole project and i dont wanna change everything. I hope it works so far. I heard about QTip, but im sure there is a way to connect those. every thing i tried instead of $( document ).tooltip doesnt work yet. Here is what I got so far. Thanks for your help. http://jsfiddle.net/algoti/Lyt9dguh/

```js
// BUTTONS ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
var clicker = rsr.set();
clicker.push(
 c1 = rsr.path("m 554.95017,1182.8675 53.08003,0 0,51.8423 -53.08003,0 z"),   c1.attr({ title: '1'}), //gfx1 on p1
 c2 = rsr.path("m 630.65654,1182.8675 53.07996,0 0,51.8423 -53.07996,0 z"),   c2.attr({ title: '2'}), //gfx1 on p2
 c3 = rsr.path("m 705.54,1182.8675 53.08,0 0,51.8423 -53.08,0 z"),            c3.attr({ title: '3'}), //gfx1 on p3
 c4 = rsr.path("m 780.8578,1182.8016 53.0801,0 0,51.8424 -53.0801,0 z"),      c4.attr({ title: '4'}), //gfx1 on p4
 c5 = rsr.path("m 897.6826,1182.8675 53.08,0 0,51.8423 -53.08,0 z"),          c5.attr({ title: '5'}), //gfx2 on p5
 c6 = rsr.path("m 972.566,1182.4593 53.08,0 0,51.8424 -53.08,0 z"),           c6.attr({ title: '6'}), //gfx2 on p6
 c7 = rsr.path("m 1048.2723,1182.8675 53.08,0 0,51.8423 -53.08,0 z"),         c7.attr({ title: '7'}), //gfx2 on p7
 c8 = rsr.path("m 1123.5705,1182.8675 53.08,0 0,51.8423 -53.08,0 z"),         c8.attr({ title: '8'}), //gfx2 on p8
 c9 = rsr.path("m 1202.1536,1182.0446 53.08,0 0,51.8424 -53.08,0 z"),         c9.attr({ title: '9'}), //gfx2 on p9
 c10 = rsr.path("m 1283.6202,1183.2823 53.08,0 0,51.8423 -53.08,0 z"),        c10.attr({ title: '10'}), //gfx3 on p10
 c11 = rsr.path("m 1359.7413,1182.4593 53.08,0 0,51.8424 -53.08,0 z"),        c11.attr({ title: '11'}), //gfx3 on p11
 c12 = rsr.path("m 1435.4476,1183.2823 53.08,0 0,51.8423 -53.08,0 z"),        c12.attr({ title: '12'})  //gfx3 on p12
);
clicker.attr({
 fill: '#000', 
 opacity: '0',
 stroke: 'none',
 cursor: 'pointer',
    href: '#',
 });
clicker.hover(
    function(){
        this.animate({
            "opacity": "0.2"
        }, 100);
    },
    function(){
        this.animate({
            "opacity": "0"
        }, 100)
    }
);
```

```css
.ui-tooltip, .ttarrow:after {
    border: 1px solid white;
 background:#19334c;
 -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
  }
.ui-tooltip {
    padding: 10px 20px;
    color: white;
    text-transform: uppercase;
 width: 150px;
 text-align:center;
  }
  .ttarrow {
    width: 70px;
    height: 16px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -35px;
    bottom: -16px;
  }
  .ttarrow.top {
    top: -16px;
    bottom: auto;
  }
  .ttarrow.bottom {
    bottom: -16px;
    top: auto;
  }
  .ttarrow.left {
    left: 50%;
  }
  .ttarrow:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    left: 20px;
    top: -20px;
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
    transform: rotate(45deg);
  }
  .ttarrow.top:after {
    bottom: -20px;
    top: auto;
  }
  .tooltip-position {
    top: -moz-calc(50% + 200px); /* Firefox */!important
 top: -webkit-calc(50% + 200px); /* WebKit */!important
 top: -o-calc(50% + 200px); /* Opera */!important
 top: calc(50% + 200px); /* Standard */ !important
}
```

```html
<script>
 $(function() {
    $( document ).tooltip({
      position: {
        my: "center top+80",
        at: "center bottom",
        using: function( position, feedback ) {
          $( this ).css( position );
          $( "<div>" )
            .addClass( "ttarrow" )
            .appendTo( this );
        }
      }
    });
  });
   </script>
```

Comment: Same as your other question. Set up a fiddle it makes people more willing to help you.

Comment: Please configure your fiddle properly, so that no framework is missing . That's why `undefined` errors are thrown in the console.

Comment: yeah - i did. i hope its now working. sorry about that size , but the project has a horizontal scroll. this is why.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/algoti/Lyt9dguh/

Comment: Does nobody have some ideas`?